# MVC Pattern Database Operations

Tags: model-view-controller

In my project, I am using mvc pattern. I do no know which class operate database operations. That's I am doing database operations in Model class, but I do not know this is correct. I have confused. Controller class maybe can be correct place insertion, deletion, update oparations. However, I do not know exactly where I have to do database operations. Also I want to search a value in database. Is model class convenient for these operations ? Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should learn more about MVC architecture. As stated on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

> The **model** manages the behavior and
> data of the application domain,
> responds to requests for information
> about its state (usually from the
> view), and responds to instructions to
> change state (usually from the
> controller). In event-driven systems,
> the model notifies observers (usually
> views) when the information changes so
> that they can react.
>
> The **view** renders the model into a form
> suitable for interaction, typically a
> user interface element. Multiple views
> can exist for a single model for
> different purposes. A viewport
> typically has a one to one
> correspondence with a display surface
> and knows how to render to it.
>
> The **controller** receives user input and
> initiates a response by making calls
> on model objects. A controller accepts
> input from the user and instructs the
> model and viewport to perform actions
> based on that input.

---

> Controller class maybe can be correct
> place insertion, deletion, update
> oparations.

No. You should do logic in Model. Controller are only used to call that functionalities.

> Also I want to search a value in
> database. Is model class convenient
> for these operations ?

You should do it in Model.